# When does suppressLineNumbers not suppress line numbers?

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I have a Word document with this style:

```
  <w:style w:type="paragraph" w:customStyle="1" w:styleId="myStyle">
    <w:name w:val="myStyle"/>
    <w:basedOn w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
    <w:rsid w:val="005F5C84"/>
    <w:pPr>
      <w:widowControl/>
      <w:numPr>
        <w:numId w:val="1"/>
      </w:numPr>
      <w:suppressLineNumbers/>
      <w:spacing w:before="240" w:line="360" w:lineRule="auto"/>
      <w:ind w:left="0" w:firstLine="720"/>
      <w:contextualSpacing w:val="0"/>
    </w:pPr>
  </w:style>
```

Because of the `<w:suppressLineNumbers/>` tag, I'd expect that Word would not show line numbers, but Word does show the line numbers.

How do I know when `<w:suppressLineNumbers/>` should take effect?  I'm not finding any good documentation on this.

Below is the paragraph in case that helps.

```
<w:p ...>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="myStyle"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00126430">
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Text</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Word line numbering is per Section, not per Style. [Add or remove line numbers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-line-numbers-b67cd35e-422c-42eb-adc9-256ca9802e22)

It's possible to drop this into the XML for a paragraph to suppress the line numbering for that paragraph:

```
<w:pPr>
    <w:suppressLineNumbers/>
</w:pPr>
```

But there's nothing analogous for use in a style. There's no online documentation for using that parameter in a style, either.